# Which jQuery Flash plugin is good?

Tags: jquery, flash

I found these three jQuery Flash plugin:

1) http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery_flash

2) http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/

3) http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/

so, which one is the best to use?

Comment: No need to put (thinly veiled) obscenity in your question. As for why you got downvoted, my guess would be that your question comes across as pretty subjective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always thought SWFObject was the best one, though I haven't tried any others. Plus you don't need jQuery itself to run it, you can just run it in vanilla JS.

Go here to see what I mean: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: +1 swfobject. Also you should look at static publishing instead of dynamic. You will get better performance.

Comment: i need to do it dynamically. :)  but thanks for advice